# Record video in QHD then reduce to FHD is the same thing of record in FHD

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7, video-recording, google-photos

I have a Galaxy S7 Flat, and I use Google Photos Unlimited backup free (which means at max/reduce videos to Full HD).

So I was wondering if I record in Quad HD (4K) has the same quality of recording​ in Full HD since the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Quad HD recording is superior to full HD as you can see from table

[image]

**[Source](https://recombu.com/mobile/article/quad-hd-vs-qhd-vs-4k-ultra-hd-what-does-it-all-mean_M20472.html)**

But if Google photos is reducing it Full HD, then the quality will be *superior* to that of a video recorded in Full HD and uploaded based on [Google Product forums](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6220791?hl=en&ref_topic=6156061&vid=0-594979366336-1489595322576)

> Videos higher than 1080p will be resized to high-definition 1080p. A video with **1080p or less** will look close to the original.

(Emphasis Added)

In other words, if the quality of recording is **less than or equal to** 1080p, it will suffer  compression losses, not if it is higher

Comment: You can probably confirm by comparing Full HD video size before and after uploading . If the file size of latter is smaller, it would point to compression losses. Not sure if this is a reliable experiment though

Comment: Were you able to check as suggested above?